# Making a Texture2D readable in Unity when loading from server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm using `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent` to get my texture:

```
www = UnityWebRequest.GetTexture("http://www.example.com/loadTex/?tag=" + tag);
www.SetRequestHeader("Accept", "image/*");
async = www.Send();
while (!async.isDone)
    yield return null;

if (www.isError) {
    Debug.Log(www.error);
} else {
    yield return null;
    tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
}
```

After loading I would like to cache it to a file so I do:

```
byte[] pic = tex.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/art/" + tag + ".png", pic);
```

At this point I get the exception:

```
UnityException: Texture '' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from 
scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.
```

I'm thinking that I need to make it readable somehow. I googled it, but the only answers I get is to how to make it readable through the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the data from UnityWebRequest. What you are dong i a bit of useless for that purpose. You turn the result into a texture to convert the texture back to byte [].

```
byte[] bytes = www.uploadHandler.data;
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/art" + tag, data);
```

I'd guess this should do. No need for the .png extension as you store a raw array of bytes. You will then get the array and create a texture out of it:

```
byte [] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/art" + tag); 
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(4,4,TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
texture.LoadImage(bytes);
```

Comment: I'm loading texture to use it in my models. But then when program ends I'm trying to cache it into the files. The reason I'm using `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent` is because it optimized for memory.

Comment: Instead of caching at the end, cache when you get it. It is quite the same.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I'll try when I get home, and report soon. Also is it less efficient to load texture from bytes instead of using `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent`

Comment: This is from the manual "To retrieve a texture file from a remote server, you may use UnityWebRequest.Texture. This method is very similar to UnityWebRequest.GET, but is optimized for downloading and storing textures efficiently."

Comment: Ok but you get me wrong, I say, you use the texture as you are doing but you store the texture as well using the way I show. The fact that what you show is faster, I got it, but next round when you use the cached version, this does not apply anyway. So when you dl, use the fast version and store the uploadHandler.data. Next, get the cache data and use a slow version which will be faster than downloading again anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to point out that UnityWebRequest.GetTexture can take two parameters: the url and a bool to make the texture readable or not :)
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.GetTexture.html

So before using DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent to get the texture in the request result. Simply call UnityWebRequest.GetTexture(url, false); so the texture downloaded become readable.

PS: Be careful, before Unity 5.6, the bool nonReadable is inverted. They should have fixed it starting 5.6 (according to release notes).

To make your texture readable:

- Before 5.6:
  UnityWebRequest.GetTexture(url, true)
- After 5.6:
  UnityWebRequest.GetTexture(url, false)